# Using "Joom" as part of extension name

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, extensions

The Joomla documentation states clearly that it's not permitted to use the word "Joomla" as part of an extension name, unless it's called "MyExtension *for Joomla!*" (except with a license):

> The usage of 'Joomla' in extension names or domains listed at JED
>   requires a license by OSM. Extension names must be titled 'for
>   Joomla'. ie: 'MyExtension for Joomla' is permitted. 'Joomla
>   MyExtension' is not permitted. Use of the Joomla version is not
>   permitted. ie: 'MyExtension for Joomla 3.0'

*([JED Entries Trademark Checklist](https://docs.joomla.org/JED_Entries_Trademark_Checklist#Use_of_Joomla_in_Extension_Names))*

But [List B1](https://docs.joomla.org/JED_Entries_Trademark_Checklist#List_B1_-_Joomla_Trademark_Checklist), item #4 on the same page says:

> Extensions that use "Joomla" or a derivative of Joomla in the
>   extension name?
>
> Only if licensed by OSM.

What does **a derivative of Joomla** mean? There are lots of extensions called **Joom** *Myextension*, isn't that a derivative of Joomla?

Answer (score 3):

A **derivative** of Joomla, simply means "*based*" on the word "Joomla".

I'll give you a quick example.

My website is called "JoomJunk" and the alias is **JJ**.

We use **JJ** at the beginning of all extension names, so **JJ XXX** is technically **JoomJunk XXX**, therefore it's a derivative of Joomla.

If you wish to use a derivative, you simply need to contact OSM to get permission for the name.

Some examples of Joomla derivatives could be:

- **Joom** Name
- **Joo** Name
- **Jom** Name
- **J** Name (like *JDownloads*)