# Using "Joomla" as part of your domain name

Tags: osm

I realise I'm taking a gamble here by asking what **could** potentially be off-topic but considering it's still related to Joomla and [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10506/using-joom-as-part-of-extension-name) wasn't closed, I thought I'd do so anyway.

Today I found a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/joomla/status/1087636140511895552) asking if users have registered for a limited license if they use the word "Joomla" in their name.

So as it stands:

1. I use the word "**joom**" in my comain name, not the full word
2. I received approval from OSM about 7 years ago for this usage
3. OSM/Joomla! have not contacted me directly stating I need this license

So my question, based on this information is, am I obligated to apply for this (new) license?

Comment: :) it’s a very unusual question here. More like a legal question which I have some relation to, but I do not think that you are obliged to do anything for using the name ‘Joom’, since legally it would also mean if you use the letter J then you should licence it from someone. They stated explicitely ‘Joomla’ in there tweet for licence.

Comment: In other words, from legal viewpoint, there is a very strict limitation of interpreting something boadly (denotative)..

Comment: And I just checked the related, earlier post on this. According to me, JoomJunk is not a derivative of Joomla in any legal meaning. JoomlaJunk could be, but JooJunk or JJJunk also not and so on... nor cannot be interpreted as derivative legally. At least, I cannot imagine that it could be a winning lawsuit in any court at the part of OSM.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/